# Exceljs, save Excel Workbook to desired file path

Tags: node.js, express, exceljs

```
const con = require("../lib/db");
const excel = require("exceljs");

const db_excel_post = (req, res, next) => {
  con.query("SELECT * FROM db", (err, details, fields) => {
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(details));

    let workbook = new excel.Workbook(); // Creating workbook
    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Profile"); // Creating worksheet

    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: "Name", key: "name", width: 10 },
      { header: "Age", key: "age", width: 10 },
      { header: "Job", key: "job", width: 20 }
    ];

    worksheet.addRows(jsonData);

    workbook.xlsx
      .writeFile("Profile.xlsx")
      .then(() => console.log("File saved!"));

  });
  res.redirect("/");
};

module.exports = {
  db_excel_post
};
```

I have tested the codes above and it is working fine. It has created "Profile.xlsx" in same directory of app.js (server).

Please see the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/izAnB.png)

Is it possible that the Profile.xlsx file can be saved/downloaded to the "public" folder? I have read through Exceljs documentation, it seems to be none of it talking about saving the .xlsx to other path. Appreciate your kind help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just include the file path in the filename.

```
workbook.xlsx
  .writeFile("./public/Profile.xlsx")
  .then(() => console.log("File saved!"));
```